# using orchestral testbench in laravel workbench - class not found

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpunit

I was able to set up PHPUnit and do some basic testing from a workbench package, but I found I couldn't use my workbench facade or do any testing of any method that used Illuminate components (for instance, my test for getting something using `Config::get()` was failing because the app hadn't really been started yet, so that facade didn't exist). I read around a few sites and saw that the Orchestral Testbench package should be able to bootstrap the app on the CLI and allow for that kind of testing, so I installed it in my main app `composer.json` file and ran `composer update orchestra/testbench`. Everything installed fine, apparently. My workbench package works just fine - both the service provider and the facade are set up in `app/config/app.php` and my test route that calls the facade and outputs a dummy string in my package config file works as expected. So I know the workbench package is set up correctly, which means my test must be set up wrong. Here's my anonymized test file:

```
class FrameworkTests extends \Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase
{
    protected function getPackageProviders()
    {
        return array('MyVendor\MyPackage');
    }

    protected function getPackageAliases()
    {
        return array(
            'MyVendor' => 'MyVendor\Facade'
        );
    }

    public function testGetConfigValue()
    {
        $this->assertStringStartsWith('foo', MyPackage::getConfigValue());
    }
}
```

When I run `phpunit` from the CLI, I get this error:

`Fatal error: Class 'MyVendor\MyPackage' not found in /home/tmountjr/projects/myproject/workbench/myvendor/my-package/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 158`

I have no idea where to go from here, nor what files to look at. Unless I'm doing something very wrong, using Testbench isn't nearly as simple as the readme makes it out to be...

ETA: got a little bit closer after sleeping on it. I realized `getPackageProviders` and `getPackageAliases` might need to look like what was in `app/config/app.php` so I modified the entries, using `MyVendor\MyPackage\MyPackageServiceProvider` and `MyVendor\MyPackage\Facades\MyPackage` respectively. Now I'm getting an error within the test:

`Non-static method MyVendor\MyPackage\MyClass::getConfigValue() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context.`

Which I think means the Facade portion isn't working, because that facade should take a non-static class method and make it available as if it were static, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the documentation doesn't make clear unless you're fluent in Laravelese is that the overloaded `getPackageProviders()` and `getPackageAliases()` methods should return the exact same lines as the `providers` and `aliases` entries in the `app/config/app.php` file. (The documentation looks like it's using a slightly different nomenclature of just vendor and package names, rather than the actual entries.) Of course this makes sense to me now after staring at it for a few hours, but it wasn't immediately clear in the docs. Hopefully this is helpful if anyone else has this issue and made the same assumptions as I did.

Comment: Do you mean that these two methods should return *everything* the same as `app/config/app.php`? ie. `'providers' => [
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,` etc....?

Comment: That's what understand from OP's answer... Yet, if you look at the code, the array returned by the test case you write is merged with the aliases defined in the "fake" Laravel app in Orchestra Testbench... Did not solve my problem: the facade from my package remains not found.

Comment: The `overrideApplicationProviders()` method actually *do* overrides all the providers and therefore needs to return providers which will register the services needed by a Laravel App.